# Perl fails stating `Variable length lookbehind not implemented`

Tags: regex, perl

I'm basically making a type of word boundary assertion.  I want to make a test for if `[abc]` is not behind and if `[abc]` is ahead and vice versa.

So I tried to make a test for it and do the negation like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
($_) = "abcdef" =~
/
((?&BB).*)
|
  (?!)
  (?<W>[abc])
  (?<NW>[^abc])
  (?<BB>
     (?<=(?&W))(?=(?&NW))
    |(?<=(?&NW))(?=(?&W))
  )
/x;
print;
```

Which doesn't work.  However, if I do this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
($_) = "abcdef" =~
/
  ((?&BB).*)
| (?!)
  (?<W>[abc])
  (?<NW>[^abc])
  (?<BB>
      (?<=[abc])(?=[^abc])
    | (?<=[^abc])(?=[abc])
  )
/x;
print;
```

It does. What's going on here?  Where's the variable length lookbehind?

FYI, I know what the message means.  I'd like to know why perl is thinking a named group is of variable length and how do I get it to stop thinking that?  To me, this looks to be a bug.  Anyone else concur?

Using versions:

```
This is perl 5, version 14, subversion 4 (v5.14.4) built for cygwin-thread-multi
This is perl 5, version 16, subversion 2 (v5.16.2) built for i686-linux
```

**EDIT**

So I found a work around which is sufficient.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$chars = qr/[abc]/;
$notChars = qr[^abc]/;
($_) = "abcdef" =~
/
  ((?&BB).*)
| (?!)
  (?<BB>
      (?<=$chars)(?=$notChars)
    | (?<=$notChars)(?=$chars)
  )
/x;
print;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The lookbehind node simply looks at its children, sees that it contains a named subrule match, and decides that a named subrule match isn't necessarily fixed-length. It doesn't look inside of the named subrule to find out that it actually *does* have a fixed length, and I'm not sure if it can given the present state of the code. Since it's unable to determine a fixed length, it can't compile the lookbehind.

Perhaps the message should be along the lines of `Can't determine the length of '(?&W)' for use in lookbehind` instead of `Variable length lookbehind not implemented`.

Comment: Well that's bloody annoying. :(  I'm giving this to you since you got the upvotes.  I've submitted it as a defect.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's here:

```
(?<=(?&W))(?=(?&NW))
    |(?<=(?&NW))(?=(?&W))
```

In Perl 5, regex doesn't support the looking behind for a variable number of captures (the stuff in the ()'s).

The ?<= and whatever follows in ()'s is where the lookbehind syntax is.

Edit: Comments below lead to clarification of question.

It looks like the variable length you have is inherent in the fact you have a named pattern for [^abc] which has a vast multitude of lengths of matches that could return. The variable length comes from the fact that any length of text can match the character class of !abc.

Perl 6 seems to support this in some fashion.

See this link to the RFC for Perl 6 regarding this issue
http://perl6.org/archive/rfc/72.html

Comment: Thanks, I know where it is and I know what it means. As far as I can tell, the two pieces of code should be equivalent.  Specifically, it's being caused by `(?<=(?&NW))`, but I don't know why it should be a failure. It is a pattern of non-variable length as defined by `(?<NW>[^abc])`.

Comment: Seems you have a good understanding of the issue, but you're confused why one works and the other doesn't? It's a Perl version thing.

Comment: What is *a Perl version thing*?

Comment: Apologies, it means the version of Perl you are using does not support the operation you're attempting to use. It looks like the variable length you have is inherent in the fact you have a named pattern for [^abc] which has a vast multitude of lengths of matches that could return.

Comment: So is this a defect?  Is there any documentation stating that it shouldn't?

Answer (score 1):

The match of a named capture has not always a fixed length, it is the reason why the regex engine doesn't allow to put a backreference in a lookbehind. Example of variable length named capture:

```
/(?|a(?<toto>ef)|b(?<toto>ghi))/
```

Comment: But testing for variable length would be feasible as it is currently done when it is not a named expression, so why isn't it done?  Also, your example isn't too good.  Please clarify.  Thanks.

Comment: @Adrian: I really don't know, I am not a regex engine developper! But hobbs answer is the kind of scenario I imagine. I don't think this is a bug, but a limitation (as fixed length lookbehinds)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug to me, but the resolution of the bug may just be to have a separate error message "Recursive capture group lookbehind not implemented" :)